# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm using Angular 2 + Google Maps Places Autocomplete in my projet it gives me this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: google is not defined

heres the html:

```
  <agm-map  id="googleMap">

  </agm-map>
```

component :

```
 ngOnInit() {
    var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.463688, 9.18814);
    var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.0438317, 9.75936230000002);

    let  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    let  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    let mapProp = {
        center:{lat:  30.42018, lng: -9.5981500},
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    };
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
//set google maps defaults
this.zoom = 4;
this.latitude = 39.8282;
this.longitude = -98.5795;

//create search FormControl
this.searchControl = new FormControl();

//set current position
//this.setCurrentPosition();

  var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "ma"}
  };
  //load Places Autocomplete
  this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
  let autocomplete = new 
  google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, 
  options);

  });
 }
```

the module:

```
 imports: [
   AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: "MyOWNKEY",
  libraries: ["places"]
}),
```

By the way I'm using AGM(Angular Google Maps)

Comment: looks like an import issue...

Comment: i think the error is with your `new google.maps.LatLng(45.463688, 9.18814);` lines. Put your library imports, because in this case the var `google` is not define

Comment: where i put the library import??

Comment: i tried to delete new google.maps.LatLng(45.463688, 9.18814); but it still gives the same error

Comment: try this exmple http://plnkr.co/edit/YX7W20?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
    declare var google.
```

put this at the top of your component.

And also, of course make sure you have added the google map script at the top of your Angular's `index.html` page

Comment: thanks for reply but the problem when i declare google map in index .html it gives me this error:You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

Comment: the index.html has just css and js files

Comment: when i delete  let  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        let  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        let mapProp = {
            center:{lat:  30.42018, lng: -9.5981500},
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
        };
        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map); it works i dont know why

Comment: dude, have you importet google map's script at the page?

Comment: open your console, try accessing `window.google` to see if it's there at all or not

Comment: i did not import google map script in index.html because its already imported in the module as mentioned above: imports: [
   AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: "MyOWNKEY",
  libraries: ["places"]
}),

Comment: when i importe it in index.html it gives me another error which is :google map declared twice

Comment: can you see it in console ? if yes, can you try `new window['google'] ....`

Comment: in which console i will try it??

Comment: Open your browser, open the console and type `window.google` , if it wasn't undefined then my solution should work

Comment: unfortunatly..it gives me undefined

Comment: there you go, so `google` is not defined at all. don't know how it works, but as far as I know, there should be a http call in your network that gets the google script downloaded

Comment: ok thank you very mutch @Milad for your help i will look for an solution.